# How do I use shell variables in Makefile actions?

Tags: bash, makefile

I have the following in a Makefile for the purpose of recreating my database including destroying it if necessary. It does not work.

```
.PHONY: rebuilddb
    exists=$(psql postgres --tuples-only --no-align --command "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname='the_db'")
    if [ $(exists) -eq 1 ]; then
        dropdb the_db
    fi
    createdb -E UTF8 the_db
```

Running it results in an error:

```
$ make rebuilddb
exists=
if [  -eq 1 ]; then
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [rebuilddb_postgres] Error 2
```

Why is this wrong? It looks like valid Bash as far as I can tell? Are there special considerations I must make when doing this in a Makefile?

**UPDATE:**

Using the answer I arrived at a working version:

```
.PHONY: rebuilddb
    exists=$$(psql postgres --tuples-only --no-align --command "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname='the_db'"); \
    if [ "$$exists" == "1" ]; then \
        dropdb the_db; \
    fi;
    createdb -E UTF8 the_db
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are at least two considerations.  `$()` references a Make variable.  You must escape the `$` to do command substitution.  Also, the shell commands must be all on one line.  Try:

```
exists=$$(psql postgres --tuples-only --no-align --command "SELECT 1 FROM \
    pg_database WHERE datname='the_db'"); \
    if [ "$$exists" -eq 1 ]; then \
        dropdb the_db; \
    fi; \
    createdb -E UTF8 the_db
```

On the other hand, it seems like it would be simpler to just always try to drop the database, and allow failure:

```
rebuilddb:
    -dropdb the_db  # Leading - instructs make to not abort on error
    createdb -E UTF8 the_db
```

Comment: There are a few more nuances about "all on one line" that are worth discussing: (traditionally and portably) everything that you want to be executed by the **same shell** must be on one logical _make_ line.  So `exists=...` and `if ... fi` must be made into a single command line with semicolons and backslashes, but `createdb ...` could happily remain as a separate second command in the recipe.

Comment: To the reader: Make sure you put the `\ ` at the end of your `VAR="foo" \ ` statement

Comment: The "all in one line" can be relaxed by using `.ONESHELL:` as described in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html#One-Shell

Answer (score 0):

## For completness the usage in $(eval $(call ...)

The usage in dynamic generation rules you have to escape the shell variables with $$$$.

### Here is an example which has been tested with "GNU Make 4.2.1":

> MY_LIBS=a b c
>
> a_objs=a1.o a2.o
>   b_objs=b1.o b2.o b3.o
>   c_objs=c1.o c2.o c3.o c4.o
>
> default: libs
>
> #  function lib_rule(name, objs)
>
> define lib_rule
>   lib$(1).a: $(2)
>   exit 1 | tee make.log ; test **$$$$**{PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0
>   endef
>
> # generate rules
>   $(foreach L,$(MY_LIBS),$(eval $(call lib_rule,$(L),$($(L)_objs))))
>
> # call generated rules
>   libs: $(patsubst %,lib%.a,$(MY_LIBS))
>
> # dummy object generation
>   %.o:%.c
>   touch $@
>
> # dummy source generation
>   %.c:
>   touch $@
>
> clean::
>   rm -f *.c *.o lib*.a make.log

The output: 'make -Rr'

> exit 1 | tee make.log ; test **$**{PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0
>   make: *** [Makefile:18: liba.a] Error 1

Result of last command in pipe is **true** from **tee**. You can see bash variable **PIPESTATUS[0]** has the value **false** from **exit 1**

Watch the Database: 'make -Rrp'

> define lib_rule
>   lib$(1).a: $(2)
>   exit 1 | tee make.log ; test **$$$$**{PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0
>   endef

...

> libc.a: c1.o c2.o c3.o c4.o
>   exit 1 | tee make.log ; test **$$**{PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0