# "sox --combine merge": how to limit the mixed output length to the shorter of the two inputs?

Tags: audio, makefile, sox

I am using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) command line tool on Linux inside a Makefile to interleave two raw (float 32 bit) input audio files into one file:

```
make_combine: 
    sox \
    --bits 32 --channels 1 --rate 48000 signal_1.f32 \
    --bits 32 --channels 1 --rate 48000 signal_2.f32 \
    --type raw --channels 2 --combine merge signal_mixed.f32
```

I ran into problems when signal_1 and signal_2 are different length. How would I limit the mixed output to shorter of the two inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `soxi -s` to find the shortest file, e.g.:

```
samps=$(soxi -s signal_1.f32 signal_2.f32 | sort -n | head -n1)
```

Then use the `trim` effect to shorten the files, e.g. (untested):

```
sox --combine merge \
    "| sox signal_1.f32 -p trim 0 ${samps}s" \
    "| sox signal_2.f32 -p trim 0 ${samps}s" \
    signal_mixed.f32
```

Note: If you want me to test it, provide some sample data.

Comment: Doesn't fully work because `samps` variable ends up empty - my Makfile is more complicated than I gave above, requires local rule variables. Anyway, this shows the way to go, which is `soxi -s`, thanks.

Comment: @Danijel: that's a `make` issue, every line is executed in its own sub-shell, also, you need to double the dollar sign to reference shell-variables. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/13774867/1331399